# What happen if I go over $150 credit limit in Azure?

Tags: azure

I have a monthly spending limit of $150 Azure credit on my subscription and it is for free.  However, I just went over it and I am wondering what happen to my charges and subscription?  Will I get charged separately from $150?  Will Azure services shut down in order to stop incurring charges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will Azure services shut down in order to stop incurring charges?

Yes. Once you exceed your spending limit, your subscription will be disabled and as a result of that your services will become inaccessible. Your subscription will be enabled automatically on your next billing start date.